# Rudin RCA Problem 4.12 (Hint Request)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integral-inequality

**Clarification and Attempted Solution**

I've been stuck on this problem for several days now, and I'm entirely frustrated at this point. I do not know how to estimate the integral in the particular way needed to obtain the desired inequalities. I have tried playing around with
$$
\int_Xc_k\cos^{\sqrt{2k}}\sin t\ dt
$$
but to no avail, and I am aware of the identity
$$
\frac{1+\cos t}{2}=\cos^2{t/2},
$$
but again I cannot see how any of this can help me come to a solution. Apologies if it seems I have not put much effort into this problem, but I just have 2-3 pages of seemingly useless inequalities written down which I see no reason to post here.

**Note**

I do not want a full solution, just a **hint** to get me going in the right direction. Leave me as much work as possible!

**Problem Statement**:

The constants $c_k$ are such that $k^{-1}c_k$ is bounded. Estimate the relevant integral more precisely and show that
$$
0<\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k^{-1/2}c_k<\infty.
$$

**Relevant Information**:

The 'relevant integral' is the Riemann integral
$$
\frac{c_k}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^k\ dt,
$$
and the estimate mentioned in the problem is
$$
1=\frac{c_k}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^k\ dt>\frac{c_k}{\pi}\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{1+\cos t}{2}\right)^k\sin t\ dt=\frac{2c_k}{\pi(k+1)}.
$$

The constants $c_k,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ are defined by the leftmost equality above. The relevant pages are in **Section 4.24** of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

Comment: A solution I wrote up years ago starts with the identity you mentioned, $(1 + \cos t)/2 = \cos^2 t/2$, and then applies $\cos x = (e^{ix} + e^{-ix})/2$. It also integrates over $[-\pi, \pi]$ instead of $[0, \pi]$, which merely doubles the result.

Comment: Awesome! I finally got back around to solving this and was able to find an explicit form for $c_k$ with your hint, and then I established the existence of $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}c_k/\sqrt{k}$ using a basic convergence test, so +1.